# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, tornado, wtforms

```
class Form(Form):
    def forms(self):
        name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        form = Form()
        self.render('index.html', form=form.forms())
```

template:

```
<form method="post" action="/test">
    {% raw form.name(type='text') %}
</form>
```

error:

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'*

---

However this works, but i need a function inside the class Form:

```
class Form(Form):
      name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        form = Form()
        self.render('index.html', form=form)
```

Comment: You probably mean to use `self.name = ...` in `Form`.

Comment: _"However this works, but i need a function inside the class Form"_ Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 5):

Your `forms()` method doesn't return anything:

```
class Form(Form):
    def forms(self):
        name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])
```

The default is to return `None` in that case. Since you pass the result of `Form().forms()` to your template, you end up with `form=None`.

If you need to set `name` on the `Form` instance only after calling a method on it, then do so in that method:

```
class Form(Form):
    def forms(self):
        name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])
        self.name = name.bind(form=self, name='name', 
                              prefix=self._prefix,
                              translations=self._get_translations())
        self._fields['name'] = self.name
        self.process()
```

where, for a `wtforms` field, you need to *bind* the field to the form before you can use it. Normally, the framework takes care of this for you.

Then call that method separately:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        form = Form()
        form.forms()
        self.render('index.html', form=form)
```

Comment: sorry, but now TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable

Comment: @anvd: What form framework is this? Most likely the `__init__` handler binds form fields when the form instance is created, and by using a method you bypassed this. **Why** do you need a separate method?

Comment: wtforms. I am thinking about a separate method because i need to pass a list of tuples to this class.

Comment: @anvd: And a custom `__init__` initializer cannot handle that?

Comment: yes, but the suggestion of @Corley Brigman give me the same error UnboundField

Comment: @anvd: Right, for additional fields created outside of the Form class, you need to manually bind them. I've added *untested* code that copies what `wtforms` does internally.

Comment: exactly the same error. Well, maybe I should avoid the method and rethink the code. thanks for your time.

Comment: @anvd: I see `.bind()` returns a bound object; refactored the code a little to store the *bound* field properly.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, but still getting errors: AttributeError: 'TextField' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: @anvd: another reason you really want to do this in `__init__` then call the parent `__init__` method. The `Form()` class also calls `self.process()`, which sets `.data` on bound fields. I added the call to my code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set an instance variable, you have to use `self`. Otherwise it's just a local variable that goes away when the function ends.

```
def forms(self):
    self.name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])
```

Comment: @Esenti given the way it was written I wasn't sure that it was supposed to return anything. I'll edit in something slightly more likely to work given my zero knowledge of tornado.

Answer (score 1):

you need a Form object with a name attribute. The second version works because it creates a Form object, with a class variable called name. The first version doesn't, because it is returning a string with the *result* of form.forms(), not the object itself.

You want this:

```
class Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])
```

then later, use the same form as before:

```
self.render('index.html', form=form)
```

If you need to CHANGE self.name later, then add a function that does the above again.

Comment: Oh, wait... the answer is obvious: you can't subclass a class from itself. Edited. Tell me if that works?

Comment: Sorry, but no. same error UnboundField' object is not callable